# How to disable previous dates in Android DatePicker?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-calendar, android-datepicker

I want to disable my past dates in `DatePicker` and show only current and future  dates... I am using the code below but this will display past dates also, please suggest the changes needed.

```
date_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            OnDateSetListener callBack = new OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                        int dayOfMonth) {
                    Calendar calender_check = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
                    calender_check.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    calender_check.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    calender_check.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    Date date2 =calender_check.getTime();


                    updatedate(sdf2.format(date2),originalFormat.format(date2));
                    Log.d("Date >>>>", ""+date2);

                    Log.d("sel_date", sdf2.format(date2));

                    date_btn.setText(sdf2.format(date2));
                }
            };
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Class.this, callBack, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

            dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
                   // Log.i(TAG, "Cancel");
                    //isCancelled = true;
                    dialog.dismiss();}
                }
            });
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably try a code like that:

`DatePicker view;
final long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1;
//Set min time to now
view.setMinDate(time);`

Answer (score 2):

before creating your DatePickerDialog,set the minimum date and then show it.

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new  DatePickerDialog(MainActiviy.this,date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),   myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
SimpleDateFormat simpledateformate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = simpledateformate.parse("21/12/2012");
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(d.getTime());
datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: after this line in your code:                                                       DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Class.this, callBack, mYear, mMonth, mDay);                                                                          just add this three lines   :                                                               SimpleDateFormat simpledateformate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = simpledateformate.parse("21/12/2012");
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(d.getTime());                           and run it...

Comment: thamk u..but it showing d cannot be resolved..can u help

Comment: datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(d.getTime());   in this line remove d  and put date reference at that place : date

Comment: i dont noe y it showing "Unhandled exception type ParseExceptio" in line Date date = simpledateformate.parse("21/12/2012"); ..i will edit my updated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97201/discussion-between-learner-and-santoxme).